# Unexpected Response Code 400 from Google Maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-android-api-2, fluttermap

I am working on a Flutter project and have to integrate Google Maps in my project. To do the same, I created a new project on Gogle console, added Maps SDK for android and other APIs I will need and took the key and copy pasted in my AndroidManisfest.xml file.

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="my_key_here"    
></meta-data>
```

Now when I go to my Map screen, it just shows me the blank page with small boxes and Google's icon on bottom left corner and zoom in and zoom out icon on bottom right corner. In console it gives error of

> **Unexpected response code 400 for https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api**

Here is the code of my map.dart screen

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class ViewMapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ViewMapsScreenState createState() => _ViewMapsScreenState();
}

class _ViewMapsScreenState extends State<ViewMapsScreen> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please guys help me out, I am stuck at a rather simple thing to implement.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the map you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks! I solved it. It seems to be an issue with the package and running flutter clean and flutter run twice solves the error. Don't know why though?

Comment: I ran flutter clean and relaunched buy it is still visible. The following line prints many times on the console: E/Volley  (14105): [620] ch.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api

Comment: did you find the solution? I am getting these so many times, I can't check my other print()!!!

Comment: anyone solve it?

Answer (score 3):

To all having this question,

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Add Package name & SHA1 Fingerprint

[image]